# How to detect and auto-open files of different types?

Tags: android

Let just say I have a PDF and a Doc file on the SD Card -- how do I auto detect which program to use to open these files?

Is this even possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Intent with application/pdf.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(pathToPdf, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: More specifically, you would use that `Intent` with `startActivity()` (to just open the file) or `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` (to get a list of activities that can open the file).